# telnet output save it to file using .bat file

Tags: windows, shell, telnet

telnet 10.0.0.22 3389 ( for checking rdp port )
I want to create a batch file, for checking two or three port, so i create a .bat file in that i have written

```
telnet 10.0.0.22 1158 >> C:\result\telnetresult.txt
telnet 10.0.0.22 3389 >> C:\result\telnetresult.txt
telnet 10.0.0.22 1159 >> C:\result\telnetresult.txt
```

but it didn't work. Can you suggest where i am doing mistake or if there is some other alternative / Workaround.
I also tried to create another .bat file with the following command.
Telnet
set logfile c:\log.txt

```
Open 10.0.0.22 80
open 10.0.0.22 1158
open 10.0.0.22 3389
```

but it also didn't work.

Comment: The tags for this question are wrong, it is tagged unix and even X11, but the question is 100% Windows command line shell.

Comment: BTW, try "telnet /?". The basis for the answer is in the output, just take into account that the file is overwritten each time, so you'll have to use the copy command to append it to another file after each 'telnet'.

Answer (score 7):

You could try `telnet “IP Address” -f “file location"`. Found the solution [here](http://www.adamstauffer.com/saving-the-output-from-a-telnet-session.htm).

Comment: But how i could do it for list of ips ??

Comment: what about the port(s)?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for port in 1158 3389 1159 
do
  echo "telnet 10.0.0.22  $port"
  echo $port |xargs telnet 10.0.0.22  >> C:\result\telnetresult.txt
done
```

some similar output

```
telnet 10.0.0.22 1158
Trying 10.0.0.22...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
telnet 10.0.0.22  3389
Trying 10.0.0.22...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
telnet 10.0.0.22  1159
Trying 10.0.0.22...
Connected to 10.0.0.22.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: I tried with this, but got error "Port was unexpected at this time" i tried with different port also.

Comment: I did the test, seems it is fine for me, can you try manually : echo 1158 |xargs telnet 10.0.0.22  , any error messages?

Comment: Seems you run the command in windows, but your question is in tags of "unix". Can you install cygwin (http://cygwin.com/install.html) ? then you can run xargs command.